# How to get the object of selected checkbox?

Tags: android, object, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I'm making a shopping list App in android with firebase, I obtain the list of items , and show in array adapter well.When I need to check an item and change it in Firebase . I don't know if I have to do that in the array adapter or in my fragment. My class is itemCart and extends from another Food that have an ID.
My problem is when I check the item, and i can't acces to the object that contains this checkbox, how can I do ?

I have this class:

```
public class itemCart extends Food implements Serializable {
    public String quantity;
    public String mesurementunit;
    public Boolean bought;


    public itemCart(){}

    public itemCart(Food food, String quantity, String mesurementunit, Boolean bought) {
        super(food.get_id());
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.mesurementunit = mesurementunit;
        this.bought = bought;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getMesurementunit() {
        return mesurementunit;
    }

    public void setMesurementunit(String mesurementunit) {
        this.mesurementunit = mesurementunit;
    }

    public Boolean getBought() {
        return bought;
    }

    public void setBought(Boolean bought) {
        this.bought = bought;
    }
}
```

Also I have this ArrayAdapter

```
public class ShoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<itemCart> {
    List<itemCart> listItemsCart;
    itemCart mitemCart;

    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    String uid;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference mitemCardReference;


    public ShoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<itemCart> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.listItemsCart = objects;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_shopping_cart,parent,false);
        }
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        uid = mFirebaseAuth.getUid().toString();
        mitemCardReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("carts").child(uid);


        TextView foodName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNameShoppingList);
        CircleImageView imgFood = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodCardCircleView);
        CheckBox checkBoxFood = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chartFoodChecklist);

        mitemCart = listItemsCart.get(position);
        checkBoxFood.setChecked(mitemCart.getBought());
        foodName.setText(mitemCart.getCorrectLanguageName()+" "+mitemCart.getQuantity()+" "+mitemCart.getMesurementunit());
        Glide.with(imgFood.getContext())
                .load(mitemCart.getImg_firebase())
                .into(imgFood);
        checkBoxFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //here i wanna get the object
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Is correct to do this in the Adapter or I  have to do in my Fragment ?

```
public class ShoppingListFragment extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    private ShoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter mshoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private CheckBox mcheckBox;
    private Button mBtnClear;

    private String uid;

    List<itemCart> itemCarts;

    private itemCart mitemCart;

    private ListView mListView;

    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mItemCartReference;

    public ShoppingListFragment (){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mItemCartReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("carts").child(uid);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_card_list,container,false);

        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lstViewShoppingCart);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarCartFoodList);
        mBtnClear = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnClearShoppingList);
        mcheckBox = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chartFoodChecklist);

        itemCarts = new ArrayList<>();

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mItemCartReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                clearItemCartList();
                for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mitemCart = itemSnapshot.getValue(itemCart.class);
                   updateitemCartList(mitemCart);
                }
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                mshoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter = new ShoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row_shopping_cart,itemCarts);
                mListView.setAdapter(mshoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



        return rootView;
    }



    private void updateitemCartList(itemCart item ) {
        itemCarts.add(item);
    }
    private void clearItemCartList(){
        itemCarts.clear();
    }

}
```

When my checkbox is clicked or changed I need to obtain the id of the object itemCart this.

In this code in the itemCart object of my arrayAdapter always recive the last one that I have.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must create interface

```
    interface ItemClickListener{
          void onItemClicked(ItemCart mItemCart);
     }
```

than update your adapter

```
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener

    public ShoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<itemCart> objects,
                                            ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.listItemsCart = objects;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }


checkBoxFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            itemClickListener.onItemClicked(mItemCart);
        }
    });
```

And pass listener to adapter like this

```
new ShoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_shopping_cart, itemCarts, new ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(ItemCart itemCart) {
        // You code to handle clicked item
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
Make your array adapter like this

```
public class ShoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<itemCart> {
List<itemCart> listItemsCart;

FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
String uid;
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
DatabaseReference mitemCardReference;

private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public ShoppingListFragmentArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<itemCart> objects,
                                        ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.listItemsCart = objects;
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_shopping_cart,parent,false);
    }
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    uid = mFirebaseAuth.getUid().toString();
    mitemCardReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("carts").child(uid);


    TextView foodName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNameShoppingList);
    CircleImageView imgFood = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodCardCircleView);
    CheckBox checkBoxFood = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chartFoodChecklist);

    itemCart mitemCart = listItemsCart.get(position);
    checkBoxFood.setChecked(mitemCart.getBought());
    foodName.setText(mitemCart.getCorrectLanguageName()+" "+mitemCart.getQuantity()+" "+mitemCart.getMesurementunit());
    Glide.with(imgFood.getContext())
            .load(mitemCart.getImg_firebase())
            .into(imgFood);
    checkBoxFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            itemClickListener.onItemClicked(mItemCart);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: the problem is , if I put

`checkBoxFood.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mitemCart.setBought(isChecked);
        }
    });`

mitemCart always have the last object that I put on the adapter on create.

not the object of the clicked checkbox

Comment: Try to pass callback into your adapter which return clicked object, like this
itemClickListener.onItemClicked(mItemCart)

Comment: sorry , i don't understand how to implement it, can you you show me an example ? ths !!

Comment: I hope it will help you

Comment: it work's,  but i don't know why I retrive the last item that I put in the  list view. When click in every checkbox :S

Comment: all the checkbox give me the last item

Comment: Can you convert your itemCart to local variable in getView, it happens cause your item cart is class field and click listener return to you state of this field, when you change scope to method you can get that item

Comment: So when you do this, u can use check listener if you want

Comment: sorry i don't understand where can I do this :S??